# Стихотворный размер в отрывке из поэмы "Измаил-бей" Лермонтова

Tags: орфоэпия

> Сидят наездники беспечно,
>   Курят турецкий свой табак
>   И князя ждут они. «Конечно,
>   Когда исчезнет ночи мрак,
>   Он к нам сойдет; и взор орлиный
>   Смирит враждебные дружины...

Нарушается ли стихотворный размер в этом отрывке из поэмы "Измаил-бей" Лермонтова?

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что если в конце строки поставить два пробела, то следующий за ними текст будет уже на новой строке.

Answer (score 2):

Сидят наездники беспечно, 248

КурЯт турецкий свой табак 2468

И князя ждут они. «Конечно,2468

Когда исчезнет ночи мрак,2468

Он к нам сойдет; и взор орлиный 2 4 6 8 (Два ударения подряд - тоже бывает)

Смирит враждебные дружины.248

Везде ямб с пиррихием (пропуск ударения),размер не нарушается.

Comment: Глаголы такого типа, как «курить», «варить», «звонить», в 19 веке  произносились с ударением на окончание.Было «курИт», стало «кУрит». Варианты «включИт», «звонИт» пока ещё держатся, но если большинство начнёт говорить "звОнит", то и это признается нормой.